# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout (no shw Slider and photos Picasso and Sliderbanner

Tags: java, android

I have this problem RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

java, android

my fragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements ILookbookLoadListener, IBannerLoadListener {

private Unbinder unbinder;

@BindView(R.id.layout_user_information)
LinearLayout layout_user_information;
@BindView(R.id.txt_user_name)
TextView txt_user_name;
@BindView(R.id.banner_slider)
Slider banner_slider;
@BindView(R.id.recycler_look_book)
RecyclerView recycler_look_book;
//FireStore

CollectionReference bannerRef,lookbookRef;

//Interface
IBannerLoadListener iBannerLoadListener;
ILookbookLoadListener iLookbookLoadListener;



public HomeFragment() {

    bannerRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Banner");
    lookbookRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Lookbook");
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this,view);

    //init
    Slider.init(new PicassoImageLoadingService());
    iBannerLoadListener =this;
    iLookbookLoadListener = this;

    //check if loged
    if (AccountKit.getCurrentAccessToken() != null)
    {
        setUserInformation();
        loadBanner();
        loadLookBook();
    }
    return view;
}

private void loadLookBook() {
    lookbookRef.get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    List<Banner> lookbooks = new ArrayList<>();
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot bannerSnapShot:task.getResult())
                        {
                            Banner banner = bannerSnapShot.toObject(Banner.class);
                            lookbooks.add(banner);
                        }
                        iLookbookLoadListener.onLookbookLoadSuccess(lookbooks);
                    }

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            iLookbookLoadListener.onLookbookLoadFailed(e.getMessage());

        }
    });

}

private void loadBanner() {
    bannerRef.get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    List<Banner> banners = new ArrayList<>();
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot bannerSnapShot:task.getResult())
                        {
                            Banner banner = bannerSnapShot.toObject(Banner.class);
                            banners.add(banner);
                        }
                        iBannerLoadListener.onBannerLoadSuccess(banners);
                    }

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            iBannerLoadListener.onBannerLoadFailed(e.getMessage());

        }
    });
}

private void setUserInformation() {
    layout_user_information.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    txt_user_name.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());
}

@Override
public void onLookbookLoadSuccess(List<Banner> banners) {
    recycler_look_book.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycler_look_book.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recycler_look_book.setAdapter(new LookbookAdapter(getActivity(),banners));

}

@Override
public void onLookbookLoadFailed(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onBannerLoadSuccess(List<Banner> banners) {
    banner_slider.setAdapter(new HomeSliderAdapter(banners));

}

@Override
public void onBannerLoadFailed(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

}

adapters

```
public class LookbookAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LookbookAdapter.MyviewHolder> {
Context context;
List<Banner> lookbook;

public LookbookAdapter(Context context, List<Banner> lookbook) {
    this.context = context;
    this.lookbook = lookbook;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_look_book,viewGroup,false);
    return new MyviewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyviewHolder myviewHolder, int i) {
    Picasso.get().load(lookbook.get(i).getImage()).into(myviewHolder.imageView);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return lookbook.size();
}

public class MyviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView imageView;
    public MyviewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_look_book);
    }
}
```

}

Slider adapter

```
public class HomeSliderAdapter extends SliderAdapter {
List<Banner> bannerList;

public HomeSliderAdapter(List<Banner> bannerList) {
    this.bannerList = bannerList;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return bannerList.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindImageSlide(int position, ImageSlideViewHolder imageSlideViewHolder) {
    imageSlideViewHolder.bindImageSlide(bannerList.get(position).getImage());

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onLookbookLoadSuccess(List<Banner> banners) {
    recycler_look_book.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recycler_look_book.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recycler_look_book.setAdapter(new LookbookAdapter(getActivity(),banners));

}
```

Your adapter only attached when the response is succeed as you see above. So if your response is not successful, your adapter will not be attached to the recyclerView. Actually it is a warning. So you should Log your response.

Comment: hi, Can you help me a little more? I'm new to this, I try to learn

Comment: Hi, how Halil can help you ?